# zf2 - using pagination control helper in controller

Tags: php, pagination, zend-framework2

i need a pagination control helper inside my controller that return JsonModel and not simple view.

this is the code

```
    $paginationHelper = new \Zend\View\Helper\PaginationControl();
    $paginationHelper->setView(new PhpRenderer());
    $paginationTxt = $paginationHelper(
        $pagination,
        'Sliding',
        array('user/user/pagination', 'User'),
        array('route' => 'user', 'action' => $action)
    );
```

$pagination is instance of Zend\Paginator\Paginator

the error is

```
    No paginator instance provided or incorrect type
```

if i put the code inside view all work fine

edit1:

i tried

```
     $view = new PhpRenderer();
        $view->paginationControl($pagination,
            'Sliding',
            array('user/user/pagination', 'User'),
            array('route' => 'user', 'action' => $action));
```

same result

i change code in this way

$paginationHelper->setDefaultViewPartial('pagination.phtml');

```
            $paginationTxt = $paginationHelper($pagination,
                'Sliding',
               null,
                array('route' => 'user', 'action' => $action));
```

all work fine

Comment: What dis your action returns ?

Comment: return json model. it's ajax call  `$json = new JsonModel($out);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get it using the ViewHelperManager

```
$viewHelperManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ViewHelperManager');
$paginationHelper = $viewHelperManager->get('paginationControl');
```

Comment: So the problem is how you are creating your paginator instance. Can you please paste how are you creating it?

Comment: please read the discussion. I create my paging adapter but when you step paginationControl helper to get the error that I have indicated. This does not happen if I put the same code in a view

Comment: No paginator instance means the paginator has not been instanciated.